# Execute Function Based On time

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIImage` that I would like to display based on the time of. For example between the hours of 9 AM and 5 PM I would like to display a image that says "open", and the rest of the time "closed". How can I accomplish this using SWIFT.

Goals:

- Execute Function Based on time of day using SWIFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these lines of code

I hope you will get the things , you are looking for

```
 let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: date)
    let hour = components.hour


    if(hour >= 9 && hour <= 17)
    {
        //set your image 'open image'
        println("Open")
    }
    else{
         //set your image 'close image'
        println("closed")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 2**

Place the following below your class:

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
```

Place this in your viewDidLoad:

```
let components = calendar.components(.Hour, fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour

if(hour >= 9 && hour <= 17) {

    // set your image 'open image'
    print("Open")

}
else {

    // set your image 'close image'
    print("Closed")

}
```